# Connect server to router with workstation in between?

Tags: connection

I have a server (9 yr old Dell with Ubuntu 10.04 Server Edition) and a workstation (a laptop with Vista) which are both connected to a router. The workstation is able to access the server via web browser for testing my web development projects.

Since the server is old and does not have a wireless card, I am wondering if it is possible to connect the server directly to the workstation while maintaining the ability to connect to the server from the workstation.

The reason is that the computers are in a separate room from the router and I am trying to limit the amount of wires on the floor, along with trying to avoid buying more hardware (like a wireless card).

Thanks and I will be more than happy to clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do what you want (and fairly easy), but it will only work if you set it up right.  Obviously you cannot connect your laptop to a server that isn't connected to the same network you laptop is connected to.  With that said, if the switch is connected to the router and the server is connected to the switch, then you will be good.  There has to be a link somewhere between the devices you want to connect.  Not sure how a switch will help you here unless it is wireless and your router is also wireless.  Without knowing your exact physical layout I would say a better option for you would be to get a cheap wireless adapter for the server, then connect it wirelessly to the same network your laptop is connected to.

EDIT:

With the new info you provided you do not even need the switch.  You are basically wanting to use your laptop as a wireless adapter for your server.  All you need to do is go to network connections in the control panel of your laptop then highlight your wireless adapter and your Ethernet adapter at the same time then right click one of them and select `Bridge Connections`.  It takes a few minutes to make the bridge, but once complete all you have to do is connect an Ethernet line between your server and your laptop and make sure your laptop is connected wirelessly to the router and you are good.  If this isn't clear post a comment and I'll make an edit.

Comment: Thanks typoknig. Sorry I should have been more clear about the setup. I am wondering if it is possible to have the server connected to the laptop in such a way that the only connection to the router is via wireless on the laptop. I am having a difficult time explaining this.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Holy cow that is amazing! Thank-you